# Connecting to Subversion 1.7.2 on Ubuntu 10.4 with TortoiseSVN 1.7.3

Tags: svn

For the past few days I have been trying to setup a Subversion SVN server on my Ubuntu 10.04 Server (Natty Narwhal Server). I've followed many different tutorials. I have looked around in the official documentation but I can not get the SVN server to work with tortoise.

My last try I did the simplest setup:
- sudo apt-get install subversion libapache2-svn
- set up a repo ('svnadmin create /path/to/repo')
- configured apache2 virtal hosts file

```
<Location /svn>
 DAV svn
 SVNParentPath /path/to/repo
 SVNListParentPath on
</Location>
```

I did not setup any accounts on the system, I did not set up any apache2 authorisation, I did not set up SSL for that host yet. I tryed to set those things up but with the same problem as result. I also tryied playing arround with permissons.

Now what happens:
After setting up the simple config above I can connect to the repo on the host itself (file:///), I can commit en can checkout. I can also browse the repo with firefox and chrome.

**EDIT** I am installing subversion on a machine in my own lan, using SSH. I tested with IP's from my router (192.168.1.100) on y laptop. That should cancel out connection/portforward trouble, I tink.

But I can not browse the repo with tools like Tortoise or Subclipse.
Why is there a difference in browsing the repo in a internet browser and in a svn tool?
What can I do to make my SVN work in the svn tools?

**EDIT 2** After the advise of Lazy Badger I tryed commiting on  the svn machine using the http protocol and got an more interesting error:
**svn: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to OPTIONS request for 'http://192.168.1.100/svn/testrepo'**

**EDIT 3** I have found the following lines in the log files of my apache2:

[Sun Jan 01 14:41:45 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.1] (20014)Internal error: Can't open file '/mnt/webserver/svn/testrepo/format': No such file or directory

[Sun Jan 01 14:41:45 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.1] Could not fetch resource information.  [500, #0]

[Sun Jan 01 14:41:45 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.1] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #2]

[Sun Jan 01 14:41:45 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.1] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #2]

and

[Mon Jan 02 07:20:40 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.109] Could not fetch resource information.  [301, #0]

[Mon Jan 02 07:20:40 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.109] Requests for a collection must have a trailing slash on the URI.  [301, #0]

---

**Updated Subversion SVN to version 1.7.2**

I have succesfully updated my Subversion SVN to version 1.7.2 by using this thread:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1876156

- The Subversion server returns a version 1.7.2
- The libapache2-svn also returns a version 1.7.2

But it still has the same problem: (from the apache2 access.log) url and ip are edited.

*84.198.xxx.xxx - - [03/Jan/2012:16:47:10 +0100] "GET /svn/testrepo/ HTTP/1.1" 200 551 "http://link.hidden.by.author:8080/svn/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20$*

*127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jan/2012:16:47:29 +0100] "OPTIONS /svn/testrepo HTTP/1.1" 403 504 "-" "SVN/1.7.2 neon/0.29.5"*

*84.198.xxx.xxx - - [03/Jan/2012:16:52:49 +0100] "OPTIONS /svn/testrepo HTTP/1.1" 403 510 "-" "SVN/1.7.2/TortoiseSVN-1.7.3.22386 neon/0.29.6"*

I didn't change any files myself. There must still be a configuration i'm missing...

---

**I solved to problem by disabling the apache2 RewriteEngine**

To summarize this into a solution:

- I updated my Subversion SVN to version 1.7.2 and the libapache2-svn module also.
- I created a repo as root
- I chown'd that repo to www-data:www-data (apache user and group)

You can also create a new user and group (e.g.: svn) but than you need to add your apache2 user (www-data) to that svn group to make the webDAV work.

- I have set group permissions to all (chmod 775)
- I have set up SSL and added this block to the virtual hosts file in apache

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl:

```
        <Location /svn>
            DAV svn
            SVNParentPath /mnt/webserver/svn
            SVNListParentPath on

            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Narwhal SVN"
            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/svn_passwd

            RewriteEngine off

            <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
                    Require valid-user
            </LimitExcept>
    </Location>
```

- It was **RewriteEngine off** that did the trick.

I've found this tip at: https://serverfault.com/questions/20169/webdav-on-centos-getting-403-error-when-attempt-to-upload

Thank you all, and specially Lazy Badger, for your help.

---

**Edit of solution:** after posting the above solution I run into a new problem. I managed to solve it in a few minutes.

If you get an error about invalid XML format when you try to do a POST command you'll probably need to set this in you dav_svn.conf or the apache2 virtual hosts file. Just add it to the  directive:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.mod_dav_svn.conf.html

```
SVNAdvertiseV2Protocol On|Off

New to Subversion 1.7, this toggles whether mod_dav_svn advertises its support for the new version of its HTTP protocol also introduced in that version. Most admins will not wish to use this directive (which is On by default), choosing instead to enjoy the performance benefits that the new protocol offers. However, whena configuring a server as a write-through proxy to another server which does not support the new protocol, set this directive's value to Off.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file:/// is pure local access method - doesn't have any security checks and doesn't use Apache DAV.

Try `svn co http://...` and check results

```
>svn co http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/
A    trunk\Hello.en.txt
A    trunk\Hello.fr.txt
A    trunk\Hello.de.txt
 U   trunk
Checked out revision 32.
```

Results of checkout from my working test-repo with anonymous read-access

Comment: Thank you, Lazy Badger, this is the first time I actually get a decent error message from the svn. **svn: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to OPTIONS request for 'http://192.168.1.100/svn/testrepo'**

I can browse the svn on that url but get the 403 forbidden error above when I try to commit something. Any ideas? I'll also look this error up my self.

Comment: I have been fiddeling arround some more and I think there might be a problem with the apache2 config for the SVN DAV module.
I can checkout a project with the file:/// protocol. After setting the permission for the users home folder and adding that user to the www-data group (the group for the svn folder on the hdd) it works smooth.
Than again using HTTP it fails on the same ERROR 403 forbidden. Any ideas?

Comment: Pls, check Apache error log for error message (it *can be* more detailed)

Comment: Also [this bug of SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3242) implies update to at least 1.6.13, while you have 1.6.12

Comment: Lazy Badger, I will try to update my subversion installation as soon as I get home again. But I think it "wierd" that I get en "older version" of subversion from apt-get. I've also look in the apache logs and found some info. I'll put it in the main question.

Comment: After updating to Subversion 1.7.2 I still have the problem with the HTTP OPTIONS command that is forbidden. I can even limit my GET to a "required valid-user" but no luck getting the OPTIONS command to work :(

Comment: 'ls -la /mnt/webserver/svn/testrepo/' pls, it seems as permissions problem or broken repo. I suggest: 1. Write full config with all bells and whistles (more easier compare with my) 2. `svnadmin create` new repo for debug

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by turning the RewriteEngine off.
If it wasn't for you tip to check the apache2 logs I would still be stuck.
Thank you very much, Lazy Badger, for you help and patience!

Answer (score 0):

What did you see when you points your browser to http://servername/svn ?

One thing, SVNParentPath should point to parent folder of your repositories, eg /path/to/repo

Then you create repositories like

```
svnadmin create /path/to/repo/repo1
svnadmin create /path/to/repo/repo2
```

Now you may be able to access then on URLs

http://servername/svn/repo1
http://servername/svn/repo2

Just one thing, make sure apache is listening on 0.0.0.0 to access from outside of host using HTTP and no iptables is running (or create rule for it).

Thanks.

Comment: When I browse http://192.168.1.100/svn/ in firefox I get: "Collection of Repositories

    * testrepo/

Powered by Subversion version 1.6.12 (r955767).

I can than click on the "testrepo" link to see a folder "project" and that link leads to the content of the one and only file in that "project". The file is a txt file with a random string. I've commited that file from the SVN machines HDD with a "svn co file:///path/to/repos/project" command"